# Redirect Selected Console Output to File

Tags: java, shell, unix, redirect, system.out

I have a small Java program that is being invoked with `java -jar` via a bash script.  The program calls a SOAP webservice and I want to capture the SOAP messages in a file for future troublshooting.  The only way I've found to do this in a standalone Java app is by adding this to my client class:

```
static
{
    // Output the SOAP message to the console
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
}
```

This outputs the SOAP messages to system out.  I could just redirect system out to a file, but I have other messages going to system out that I want to be displayed on the console.  It's okay to include these messages in the file but the SOAP messages are just way too much to be displayed on the console.

Is there a way I can do some sort of selective redirect on console output?

Comment: If the other messages going to the console are your own then you could prepend them with a special symbol and then filter the output through an appropriate script.

It seems unlikely that you'll be able to do this in-app the SOAP code will be calling System.out.print.

Comment: @selig  Yes, that's what I ended up doing.  If you add your comment as an answer, I'd gladly accpet it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems unlikely that you'll be able to do this in-app as the SOAP code will be calling System.out.print.

If your main goal is to separate your output from the output from SOAP then you could  prepend your messages with a special symbol and then filter the output through an appropriate script.

If your print statements are spread across your code you could consider using AOP (i.e. AspectJ) to modify them to insert this special symbol. Personally I do all printing through my own utility methods so that I can change it all in one place if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the SOAP library you are using, but generally most SOAP libraries have some sort of logging facility they use when writing things out to the console.  Typically when you use these logging facilities the SOAP library itself doesn't write directly to System.out.  The logging facility is configured to write that data to System.out by default.   So if you figure out which SOAP lib you're using, then figure out what logging facility it uses, then you can configure logging to write to a file instead of System.out, but still send other messages to System.out.

I think you're using Metro which is using Java Util Logging. Not as easy to configure, but it can be configured with multiple appenders and loggers.  I think this will be helpful for you:

https://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#logging

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I looked into if Metro actually logs the SOAP messages or simply writes them them to System.out.  Couldn't find the source code, but all referecences I could find state it's to System.out.  To double check, I changed my program to use java.util.Logging directly (vice SLFJ) and the SOAP still doesn't get logged to the log file.

Comment: The docs aren't specific about how to configure the logging system, but I did find evidence that if you can figure out how to configure logging using a new logging.properties file it will redirect it.  Changing your program to use java.util.Logging won't affect the configuration of the logging in SOAP per se.  You have to change the logging.properties config file to do that.

Comment: It was an interesting/frustrating experiment for me to use java.util.logging as I've always used Log4J and now Logback.  So, it's quite possible that it could be done, but it isn't worth the hassle for me when I've found a solution as per above.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write the messages you want to capture to *stderr* and redirect that appropriately? One thin you should consider is that *stdout* is [usually] buffered and *stderr* is not.

You're looking for *shell redirection and piping*. Assuming you're using a standard-ish shell like shell, bash, csh, etc. ...

- `command >foo.txt` will **redirect** *stdout* to the file `foo.txt`. Any existing content in the fill will be replaced.
- `command >>foo.txt` will **redirect** *stdout*, appending it to the file `foo.txt` to the existing content, if any, of `foot.txt`.
- `foo | bar` will **pipe** the content of command `foo`'s `stdout` through command `bar`'s stdin.

A *nix process has three standard i/o handles open:

- *stdin* is **standard input**. It is file handle 0.
- *stdout* is **standard output**. It is filehandle 1.
- *stderr* is **standard error**. It is filehandle 2.

The redirection and pipe operators can hook specific file handles as well. So...

```
command >foo.txt 2>&1
```

does the following:

1. Redirects standard output to the file `foo.txt`
2. Redirects *stderr* to file handle 1, *stderr*, which is now opened as `foo.txt`.

Other shells can (and do) use different, but generally similar syntax.

You should also learn about some useful commands:

- `tee(1)`.

  This takes the stdin given it and writes it to file specified on the command line as well as to stdout, so a chain like this:

  ```
  some-command 2>&1 | tee some-command.log.2013-05-31.txt | less
  ```

  runs `some-command`, which presumably produces a goodly amount of output, redirecting its stderr to stdout, which is then piped through `tee(1)`, producing a logfile, `some-commmand.log.2013-05-31.txt` and piping it through `less(1)` to page it on your console.
- `less(1)`
- `more(1)`

  `more` is usually a synonym for `less(1)` these days. both of these are *pagers* which buffer output and dispaly it a screen at a time, letting you page forwards and backward through it.
- `man(1)`
- `apropos(1)`

  This is *nix's online help system. To learn more about them, try running these commands:

  ```
  * `man man`
  * `man apropos`
  ```

  To get the *man page* for the `man` and `apropos` commands. You might also try `man tee`, or `man [your-shell-name]` for the specific shell you're using (e.g., `man csh` will get you the man page for the `csh` shell, whilst `man sh` will get you the Bourne shell (`sh`) man page and `man bash` will get you the `bash` man page.

This page describes the usual piping/redirection operators for the C and Bourne shell families: http://www.mathinfo.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html

You should also read the appropriate O'Reilly `Nutshell` book:

- [Unix In A Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100292.do)
- [Linux In A Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596154493.do)

**Edited To Note:**
As I mentioned in the comment below, you can replace `System.Out` and `System.Err` with your own `PrintStream`, along these lines:

```
PrintStream originalStdOut = System.Out ;
PrintStream newStdout = CreateNewOutputSink() ;

System.Out.flush() ;
System.Out.setOut( newStdout ) ;

invokeSome3rdPartyCode() ;

System.Out.flush() ;
System.Out.setOut( originalStdout ) ;
```

This will let you hook the output from your 3rd party library and redirect it to the data sink of your choice, whilst not affecting your ordinary output. If you hook both `System.Out` and `System.Err` and redirect them to the *same* `PrintStream` you'll catch both standard and error output in the process.

Comment: "Why not write the messages you want to capture to stderr and redirect that appropriately?"  Because it's code in a library that I'm using that's doing the writing to System.out and I can't change that.

Comment: @sdoca, then it would seem you are kind of stuck. You can however, *replace* `System.Out` and `System.Err`, setting them to your own `PrintStream` via `System.setOut()` and `System.setErr()`. Save the current `System.Out`, flush its buffers, set `System.Out` to your own `PrintStream`, invoke the code whose output you want to hook, flush `System.Out`'s buffer and restore the original `System.Out` print stream. See my amended answer for a [rough] example.

Comment: That may be a viable solution if I was invoking the code directly that is using System.out to dump the SOAP messages.  However, it's all hidden in layers of framework libraries.